# How to generate a different amount of rows and columns in a table

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I got a table with three columns (name, date, secret) and dynamical rows. I would like to have two head rows. The first and third column should use the first and second head row as just one row. I know I can do that with rowspan = "2". The Problem now is that I need the second head row to have four columns. I need to have the second and third column in the second row to be as big as the "date"-column in my first row. So I want to break my "date"-column into "begin" and "end". So just to have a begin time and an end time.
So my first row is Name, date, secret.
My second row should be Name, begin, end, secret but as big as the first row. Date should be just splitted in begin and end.

See my code with drop-down-menu and checkbox below. I did not include the second head row because I do not know how.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head><title>Shared Secrets</title></head>

<body>
    <h1>Shared Secrets</h1>
<table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:red"></col>
            <col width="165"></col>
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:grey">
            <th>plane
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="filterReports()">
                     <option selected="selected">All</option>
                     <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane">
                        <option>
                         <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </option>
                     </xsl:for-each>                    
                </select>                   
            </th>   
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Secret
                <input type="checkbox" id="identicalSecrets" onchange="identicalSecrets()"></input>
                <label for="identicalSecrets">hide identical secrets</label>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../Name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="secret"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../../filterReports.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src=/../../identicalSecrets.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as last time: use the maximum number of columns/rows you need as base, then use `rowspan` / `colspan` to join cells. Here's the fiddle from last time, modified to match the new requirement: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wg6f0dm2/ See also here: https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

Comment: That's not what your question says, which asks for the Date column being split in two. Anyway, maybe you should sketch the structure you want and add it to the question? edit: ....and you removed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

> **HTML  rowspan Attribute**
>
> Example:
>
> An HTML table with a table cell that spans two rows:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr>
>     <th>Month</th>
>     <th>Savings</th>
>     <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>January</td>
>     <td>$100</td>
>     <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>February</td>
>     <td>$80</td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```
>
> **Definition and Usage** The rowspan attribute specifies the number of rows a cell should span.
>
> **More Examples**
>
> Example Using rowspan="0":
>
> ```
> <table>
> <thead>
>   <tr>
>     <th>Month</th>
>     <th>Savings</th>
>     <th rowspan="3">Savings for holiday!</th>
>   </tr>
> </thead>
> <tbody>
>   <tr>
>     <td>January</td>
>     <td>$100</td>
>     <td rowspan="0">$100</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>February</td>
>     <td>$80</td>
>   </tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp